# Sqlite3 delete by primary key

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I am using Node with [node-sqlite3](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3). I cannot seem to delete rows by passing their primary key, but I can delete rows by passing some other column value.

**Works**

```
    this.db.run("DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE Name = 'Bob'");
```

**Does nothing**

```
    this.db.run("DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE _id = 3);
```

I have specified _id as my autoincrement / primary key. I can prove this by doing a `PRAGMA` and showing the debugger's results here, which clearly indicates `_id` as the `pk`

**PRAGMA call**

[image]

**Debugger**

[image]

I really don't know what to do as I get no errors from the `db.run` call

Comment: 1. Are you sure you have a row where `_id = 3`? Open the DB with the `sqlite` binary to make sure. 2. Are you passing an error callback to `db.run` to make sure you aren't, in fact, getting an error?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I second Ltn.32. I would like to see the result of this.db.run("SELECT _id FROM MyTable WHERE Name = 'Bob'");

Comment: Thanks. It turned out that deep in my UI table generator I was adding an `_id` property to each row, and that was overriding the actual column value